# Scala, regex matching ignore unnecessary words

Tags: regex, scala

My program is:

```
val pattern = "[*]prefix_([a-zA-Z]*)_[*]".r

val outputFieldMod = "TRASHprefix_target_TRASH"

var tar =
  outputFieldMod match {
    case pattern(target) => target
  }

println(tar)
```

Basically, I try to get the "target" and ignore "TRASH" (I used *). But it has some error and I am not sure why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple and straight forward standard library function (unanchored)**

Use ***Unanchored***

---

***Solution one***

Use `unanchored` on the pattern to match inside the string ignoring the trash

```
val pattern = "prefix_([a-zA-Z]*)_".r.unanchored
```

`unanchored` will only match the pattern ignoring all the trash (all the other words)

```
val result = str match {
 case pattern(value) => value
 case _ => ""
}
```

**Example**

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val pattern = """foo\((.*)\)""".r.unanchored
pattern: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = foo\((.*)\)

scala> val str = "blahblahfoo(bar)blahblah"
str: String = blahblahfoo(bar)blahblah

scala> str match { case pattern(value) => value ; case _ => "no match" }
res3: String = bar
```

---

***Solution two***

Pad your pattern from both sides with `.*`. `.*` matches any char other than a linebreak character.

```
val pattern = ".*prefix_([a-zA-Z]*)_.*".r

val result = str match {
   case pattern(value) => value
   case _ => ""
}
```

**Example**

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val pattern = """.*foo\((.*)\).*""".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*foo\((.*)\).*

scala> val str = "blahblahfoo(bar)blahblah"
str: String = blahblahfoo(bar)blahblah

scala> str match { case pattern(value) => value ; case _ => "no match" }
res4: String = bar
```

Comment: A dot in Scala regex will match any char other than a linebreak character. Not just alphanumeric or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, `val pattern = ".*prefix_([a-z]+).*".r`, but it distinguishes between target and trash via lower/upper-case letters. Whatever determines *real* target data from trash data will determine the *real* regex pattern.